# Overwrite style properties on select in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to reuse my basic style function to create an select style by overwriting some of the properties.
This approach is working for fill/stroke colors of linestrings, polygons and texts, but not for images (a circle in my case).
I don't want to create a new image since other properties should be retained.

```
var selectStyleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  var style = styleFunction(feature, resolution)[0];
  style.getImage().getFill().setColor("magenta");

  console.log(style.getImage().getFill().getColor());

  return [style];
};
```

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ha5c4zd/) you can see, that the above code doesn't change the feature style on selection although the log output is correct.

Is there any way to overwrite this property?

Comment: There's a discussion about this: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/5775

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i don't see where this discussion relates to my problem. As i understand it, it's about efficiency when drawing circles.

Comment: As you can see the referenced issue https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6233 there may be some kind of information.

Comment: That's the information i needed. I have to change the radius to force rerendering. You can create an answer if you want, so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question in the api dokumentation of openlayers. It was too obvious to find it in the first place.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.Style.html

> **ol.style.Style**
>   Container for vector feature rendering styles. Any changes made to the style or its children through set*() methods will not take effect until the feature or layer that uses the style is re-rendered.

So rendering is not triggered by the setters.